# Implementing Diffie Hellman Key Exchange on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I'm a complete beginner in crypto. What I know about Diffie Hellman Key exchange is:

1. One Public key is generated and is world readable.
2. Sender and Reciever generate their own Private keys independent of each other or the public key
3. They mix their pvt keys with public key and send to each other
4. They mix the recieve d key with their respective pvt key and end up getting same key which is known by no one else.
5. They can now use any symmetric key crypto to encrypt and decrypt.

The question is: Is this computationally possible in javascript?

Comment: Try to post this question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is computationally possible (most algorithms are, given enough time and memory). However, I think you should read more into DH, because the above scheme isn't it. And if you have read into it, continue with ECDH because it will perform much better on Java Script.

Also note that implementing cryptography in Java Script has many pitfalls, especially if run within the browser, and even more so if it is run within the browser without TLS.

Comment: About browser JavaScript cryptography: http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/